# How can I install packages from Debian's squeeze repo on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, apt, package-management, debian, unsupported-packages

I am using Debian Squeeze but I want to test Ubuntu with Unity.

I just downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 ISO and installed it, but I can't find a way to add Debian's local repository.

How can I use Debian's DVD repo with Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### general warning

In general mixing Debian and Ubuntu is not a good idea, because there are some slight differences.

Keep in mind the Ubuntu releases are not a branch of the current *Debian stable*.
Normally the packages are synchronized with *Debian unstable* some time before the Ubuntu release is finished.

Also some special *Ubuntu* patches may have been applied.

**Mixing *Debian* and *Ubuntu* repositories will likely render your system unmaintainable.**
The package dependencies may introduce contradictions which leads to a deadlock situation.

### possible solutions

#### adding Debian repository to `apt`

You have been warned above.
If you insist to try it, you can add the Debian DVD to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. See [`man sources.list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sources.list.5.html) for details

#### manual install with `dpkg`

1. Install the *Debian* package with `dpkg --force-depends <package.deb>`.
2. Afterwards try to resolve the missing dependencies with `apt-get install -f`.
3. If one dependency can't be satisfied by *Ubuntu*, go back to **1.** and install it also this way.

This is better as the 1st approach, but over the time you can run in dependencies problems, if you update your system with `apt-get upgrade`.

#### use Launchpad ppa

My advice is that you create a **Launchpad** account and a **ppa repository**.
Also install the `ubuntu-dev-tools` package.

With the following command you can fetch a Debian source and try to compile it for Ubuntu:

```
backportpackage --upload=ppa:${LAUNCHPAD_USER}/${PPA_NAME}  --source=squeeze --destination=quantal   ${SOURCE_PACAKGE}
```

To install it, simply use `apt-add-repository` to add your *ppa repository* to your *apt* configuration.

This way is maybe a little bit more complicated, but will help you to ensure that the dependencies are not getting broken.

### using ubuntu packages in debian

As above with switching debian with ubuntu and vice versa.

**The warning applies as before.**

Instead of using a launchpad ppa, you have to grab the sources manually from ubuntu and try to compile them with e.g. `pbuilder` yourself.

Likely it will fail, if you using *debian squeeze* because *ubuntu quantal* is as written above a "fork" from *debian unstable*.

Comment: but how can i install unity on Debian Squeeze ?!

Comment: This is not focus of ask**ubuntu**.