# How to add Debian experimental repo to Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, package-management, repository

I would like to install `cups-1.6.1-2` ([link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/1.6.1-2)) from the [experimental](https://launchpad.net/debian/experimental) repository.

I suppose I have to add something to `/etc/apt/sources.list` but I can't figure out what.

Can anyone figure out (or know) how to add the experimental repo?

Comment: Why do you need CUPS `1.6.1-2`?  I can create a PPA that can hold that package if you really need it, but I can't recommend to ANYONE to use Experimental's repository

Comment: @TheLordofTime It is because Ubuntu 12.10 uses cups 1.6.1 which have a regression bug that prevents it from working with cups 1.4.x and 1.5.x servers. So I can't print when I am at school. So I would be very grateful for a PPA =)

Comment: Please give me the bug number.  I will try and backport Raring CUPS 1.6.1-2 to Quantal in a PPA, and add that to my answer with the standard "THIS IS A PPA" warning I give everyone.

Comment: It is this one 1069671. At the bottom they write that it is fixed in 1.6.1-2.

Comment: And even further at the bottom, it shows it's not *fully* fixed.  So even with a backport it won't be completely fixed (read to the end of the bug).  I will still try and backport later, I have a meeting I have to be at.

Comment: Status update: I'm test-building the backport of CUPS 1.6.2-1ubuntu2 to Quantal in a PPA.  I'll add it to my answer if it builds correctly, and include the "THIS IS A PPA!" warning.

Comment: Sandra, I can't backport the version of CUPS from Raring to Quantal or Precise.  Not without upgrading gnome-keyring in the process, and I'm not entirely sure that's safe.  I can't convince you to wait until Raring's out, can I?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I'll then use lpd drivers until 13.04.

Comment: Actually, Sandra, if you're REALLY REALLY REALLY feeling daring, you can try and use what's in my PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~teward/+archive/cups-backports/+packages), but I haven't tested that AT ALL.  So you'd be using that at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

The Experimental repository is a **Debian repository**, not an Ubuntu repository.

I would **NOT RECOMMEND** using the Experimental repository as a source for anything.  It has a lot of packages which can break everything, hence the name "Experimental".

CUPS `1.6.1-2` exists in Raring.  Once raring is released, you can use Raring.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit sources.list:**
                    '/etc/apt/sources.list'

**Add the repo URL like below**.
                    'deb http://dev.zenoss.org/deb main stable'

Comment: The problem is I can't figure out what the URL is.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't mix Debian and Ubuntu repositories:

> **Mixing *Debian* and *Ubuntu* repositories will likely render your system unmaintainable**. The package dependencies may introduce contradictions which leads to a deadlock situation.

Please read further in the following answers: https://askubuntu.com/a/240654/58950 and https://askubuntu.com/a/264766/58950