# Installing softwares in ubuntu using other linux distro .ISO

Tags: repository, iso, offline

I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 x64 installed (without internet) and also have the .ISO file of Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca x64. I want to install some packages like Gimp, media player codecs, VLC in my Ubuntu using the .ISO of Linux Mint. How do I make this possible? Actually I want to use Linux Mint .ISO as an offline software repository for my Ubuntu.

Comment: You do not mix repositories.

Comment: Just to make it clear: You do NOT mix repositories. Either use Mint or Ubuntu. If you choose the 1st we can not help you and you need ask questions here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/  Ubuntu is an internet based operating system ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add Debian experimental repo to Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270014/how-to-add-debian-experimental-repo-to-ubuntu) *Mixing Debian and Ubuntu repositories will likely render your system unmaintainable. The package dependencies may introduce contradictions which leads to a deadlock situation.* The same goes for mixing Mint and Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install packages on an offline system, apt ist prepared for this.

This [link](http://docs.xubuntu.org/1304/offline-packages.html) is for xubuntu, but it will also work on your ubuntu system.

All you need is another system with apt and internet access.