# Safe to add Debian Testing repos to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, repository, debian

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My question is about this: Is it safe to add the Debian Testing Repositories to Ubuntu 20.04? I want to have newer software available and software that is Ubuntu specific only (eg. Unity / Virtualbox). Will my system break?
I added this to my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-testing.list`, am I missing a repo?:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing-updates main
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian testing-updates main
```

When I do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, I receive the result that almost 1GB must be downloaded and that many packages "are no longer required". Is this ok? I dont want to remove those packages, as I need them!
Is it safe to perform this upgrade? Will I loose my system?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/240646, https://askubuntu.com/q/264764 and [DontBreakDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian)

Comment: "Safe to add Debian Testing repos to Ubuntu 20.04?" No. An unworkable system is more likely; Maybe not immediately but it only takes 1 updated library that is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If the packages are no longer required, do not run `sudo apt autoremove` without first checking or your system might break. The Debian Testing repos might contain duplicate packages which might cause problems. Anyway, why do you want to add those repos?

Comment: I dont want to run `sudo apt autoremove` because there are packages that I need. And I would like to add the Debian Testing repos to have newer software available.

Comment: Then you should install debian.

Comment: why do you want to add it to Ubuntu then?